# Why do we put on tallis katan but without a bracha on Tisha b'Av?

Tags: tallit-katan

The Artscroll Tisha b'Av siddur states clearly that we don tallis katan in the morning of Tisha b'Av but without a bracha.  What is the logic behind donning but without a bracha?

Answer (score 1):

The Shulchan Aruch [555:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.555.1?lang=he&with=Commentary&lang2=he) states this halacha

> נוהגים שלא להניח תפילין בתשעה באב שחרית ולא טלית אלא לובשים טלית קטן תחת בגדים בלא ברכה ובמנח' מניחים ציצית ותפילין ומברכים עליהם

The MB brings some who say that if one did not wear tzitzis during the night, he would indeed make a bracha in the morning on the tallis katan.

R' Shlomo Zalman Aurbach was said to have made sure to wear tzitzis on Tisha Ba'v night to avoid this issue.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question. What is the reason for the practice?

Comment: It would seem the MB was concerned as well and suggested it depended on wearing it all night in which case a bracha on regular day isn’t really needed

Comment: It sounds like you're just saying some people disagree with the practice. That's not really an answer for why the practice exists

Answer (score 0):

Probably for the same reason we don’t wear Talis during Shacharis and why we don’t kiss the tzizit in the Shema. It’s based on a Targum to Lamentations 2:17, which renders בִּצַּע אֶמְרָתוֹ as בִּזַּע פּוּרְפִירָא דִילֵיהּ - He rent His royal robes. We still wear tzizit, but we “diminish” it and “downgrade” it by not acknowledging it as we usually do, such as by saying a bracha on it or kissing it.